# Set English as default language in Localization iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, localization, nslocale

getting issue here:
How to set English as default language for non-implemented languages in MultiLingual app. If changing language to e.g. Hrvatski or Polish which are not implemented the App does not use English as default language but seems to remember the last language used like(Dutch) in my case it continues to use Dutch…

How to set back to English is app does not support to Phone selected Language.

Comment: Try this!!https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-localization-apps/

Comment: @Sanjeetverma Thanks for replying. but this tutorial even not able to solve the problem, So First you select french in iPhone settings, run the application, the app language changes to french. Now go back to Iphone setting and change the language to Dutch, again start the app, app still shows the French language, it should show english as default language. try the steps.